# Rails 4 not rendering ajax after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Part of js works, only the re-rendering isn't happening unless I hit refresh on the browser, so, the data is being sent and created in the db but js isn't rendering new data.

My JS:

```
 $('#myform').submit(function() {  
    var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
      $(this).find('textarea').addClass('uneditable-input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
    }).complete(function(json){
        //act on result.
      //alert("submitted");


     $("#disabletext").removeClass('uneditable-input').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
        #this line below is the only thing that doesn't work
       $('#indexstream').html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'postline') %>");

      #this line works, but it hides the most recent post in the index and shows it again
      #but the most recent post should be the one after this form submits
      $("#userlink").hide().show("slow").effect('highlight', {}, 3000);




    });   
    return false; // prevents normal behaviour
});
});
```

view:

```
<div id="indexstream">

   <%= render 'postline' %>

          </div>
```

_postline.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

            <div id="streamline"> 

            <div id ="userlink">

              <%= image_tag post.avatar.url(:small), :style => "border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #e1e8ed;" %> 
           <%= post.firstname %> <%= " "  %>  <%= post.lastname %><%= " " %>  <%= link_to post.email, user_path(post.user_id), {class: "usernamelink", style: "font-weight: normal;"} %>

  <abbr class="timeago" title="<%= post.created_at.getutc.iso8601 %>" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px; font-size:90%;
                                                                             margin-top: 12px; color: #8899a6; text-decoration: none !important;">
    <%= post.created_at.to_s %>
</abbr>



            <br /><br />
              <% unless post.description == "status" %>
               <div style="background: #EF4836; width: 10px; height: 5px; float: right; margin-top: -58px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px; color: #fff; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; margin-right: 5px;">
              </div>
            <h1 style="style= z-index: 100000; color: #3399FF "><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post), {class: "usernamelink", style: "color: #3399FF;"} %></h1>


               <% if post.asset1.file? %>
            <%= image_tag post.asset1.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset2.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset2.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset3.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset3.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset4.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset4.url(:small) %>
            <% end %>
              <br /><br />
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px;"></i>  <%= post.school %>  <div style="float: right; text-align: left; margin-right: 20px;"> <i class="fa fa-usd "></i><%= post.price %></div>

              <% end %>
              <% if post.description == "status" %>
              <div style="background: #2ECC71; width: 10px; height: 5px; float: right; margin-top: -58px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px; color: #fff; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; margin-right: 5px;">

              </div>
              <h1><%= auto_link( post.title ) %></h1>


                    <% if post.asset1.file? %>
            <%= image_tag post.asset1.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset2.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset2.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset3.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset3.url(:small) %><% end %> <% if post.asset4.file? %><%= image_tag post.asset4.url(:small) %>

            <% end %>
             <br /><br />

              <% end %>






           </div>
         </div>  

<% end %>
```

posts controller create method:

```
def create

    @post = Post.new(post_params) 
    @post.email = current_user.username
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    @post.firstname = current_user.firstname
    @post.lastname = current_user.lastname
    @post.avatar = current_user.avatar
    @post.school = current_user.school


    respond_to do |format|  
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path, :notice => '<i class="fa fa-check fa-5x"></i>'.html_safe }
       # format.js   # @current_item = @post 
        format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @post }
        #format.html {render 'postline'}


      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
       format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end
```

The code looks good to me, I can't seem to get it working at all. I need you all, been working on this for days without any results

Comment: In your ajax, where is the `success:` element ? because of which, you can replace the html content with your ajax o/p.

Comment: oh, so the .html wouldn't work in ajax complete?

Comment: changed `complete` to `success` no changes

Comment: so in ajax we have two events `success:` and `error:`. Once you have submited the ajax, the response should be again coming to our html page right ? ..so for example, we can mention, on `sucess:`(of ajax) replace this particular <div> in our html page with ajax response. If error, then example `alert('something went wrong')`

Comment: can you attempt to answer in code so I know what you mean?

Comment: complete is not to show your ajax request in html.. for example, if you requested an ajax, and it is taking time.. as we have seen in many sites, it shows spinning wheel when loading right ? so, we can mention between `ajax start` and `ajax complete` run this spinner ...thats it

Comment: sure, its not exact but, something like ... success: function(response){ $('.class').html(response); }, error: { alert('something went wrong');}

Comment: I did that, no change

Comment: you have to go through the proper syntax of ajax, before going through the code. Your code is missing those params. `http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/ajax_ajax.asp`